# How to push html to draft with react-draft-wysiwyg and draft js?

Tags: html, reactjs, editor, draftjs, react-draft-wysiwyg

I get a Html string from my API : `"consigne": "<p>test</p>\n"` and I want to display it on my editor.

My Editor is :

```
<Editor id="consigne" name= "consigne" editorState={consigne} value={draftToHtml(convertToRaw(consigne.getCurrentContent()))} onEditorStateChange={(consigne) => {this.setState({consigne})} localization={{ locale: 'fr' }}/>
```

I want to insert this consigne on my editor.

How I can push this consigne to my editor ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it by this :

```
  this.setState({ 
consigne:EditorState.createWithContent(ContentState.createFromBlockArray(convertFromHTML(plan.consigne))) 
    })
```

Comment: thanks a lot for posting, however no longer working for current version `"react-draft-wysiwyg": "^1.14.5",`

Answer (score 0):

For the recent version:

```
const blocks = convertFromHTML(plan.consigne);
this.setState({ 
  consigne: EditorState.createWithContent(ContentState.createFromBlockArray(blocks.contentBlocks, blocks.entityMap)) 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Approach using functional components:

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { EditorState, convertFromHTML } from 'draft-js';
import { ContentState } from 'react-draft-wysiwyg';

const blocks = convertFromHTML(htmlData);
const [editorState, setEditorState] = useState(() =>
     EditorState.createWithContent(ContentState.createFromBlockArray(blocks.contentBlocks, blocks.entityMap))
);
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post to explain your code. Code only answers are unhelpful